# Python `inspect.Signature` shows all defined positional arguments as `ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD`

Tags: python-3.x, reflection, inspect

I had the impression that you could use the `inspect.Signature` function to retrieve and distinguish between positional and keyword arguments. However this does not seem to be the case:

```
def foo(a,b,c, t=3, q=5):
    print(a,b,c,t,q)

[(u, u.kind) for u in i.signature(foo).parameters.values()]

[(<Parameter "a">, <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>),
 (<Parameter "b">, <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>),
 (<Parameter "c">, <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>),
 (<Parameter "t=3">, <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>),
 (<Parameter "q=5">, <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>)]
```

So, as it is, seems the `kind` attribute is pretty useless to distinguish between positional and keyword arguments

So the question here is:

How do I distinguish between arguments `a,b,c` and arguments `t,q` so that if I were to invoke foo:

```
  #build args from signature with args = [a,b,c]
  #build kwargs from signature with kwargs = {'t': t,'q': q}
  foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Greenstick not a solution, but the workaround is to avoid positional arguments altogether if possible

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I may have found the answer – looks like it may be a Python 3.8+ behavior. Writing it up now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Unless you explicitly define function parameters as being `POSITIONAL_ONLY` or `KEYWORD_ONLY` using the syntax below, the default behavior is for all parameters to be `POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD`. A difference exists between the behavior of Python 3.8+ and previous versions of Python.

### Python 3.8+

In Python 3.8+ whether an argument is positional only or keyword only can be specified using the `/` and `*` syntax, respectively. As an example:

```py
def f(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
      -----------    ----------     ----------
      |              |              |
      |              Positional or  |
      |              keyword        Keyword only
      Positional only
```

Everything before `/` is positional only; everything after `*` is keyword only. Note that order matters – `/` must come before `*`. Also, if you don't explicitly specify `POSITIONAL_ONLY` or `KEYWORD_ONLY` using this syntax, all arguments default to the `POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD` value for the `kind` attribute.

This is due to a change that was made in Python 3.8. The behavior of the `/` syntax was specified in [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) (following [PEP 457](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/)). In code:

```py
>>> import inspect

# Positional or keyword (default behavior)
>>> def meow (a, b, c = 0, d = 1):
...    return (a * b + c) * d

>>> {p.name: p.kind for p in inspect.signature(meow).parameters.values()}
{'a': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'b': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'c': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'd': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>}

# Positional only, positional or keyword, keyword only
>>> def meow (a, /, b, c = 0, *, d = 1):
...    return (a * b + c) * d

>>> {p.name: p.kind for p in inspect.signature(meow).parameters.values()}
{'a': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_ONLY: 1>, 
 'b': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'c': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'd': <_ParameterKind.KEYWORD_ONLY: 1>}
```

### Before Python 3.8

Prior to PEP 570, the `/` syntax did not exist but the `*` syntax did (haven't been able to find the exact PEP when it was introduced); trying the `/` in 3.7 raises a syntax error:

```py
# Python 3.7 - we get an error if use the `/` syntax
>>> def meow (a, /, b, c = 0, *, d = 1):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def meow (a, /, b, c = 0, *, d = 1):

# If we omit the `/` but keep the `*`, it works
>>> def meow (a, b, c = 0, *, d = 1):
...    return (a * b + c) * d

>>> {p.name: p.kind for p in inspect.signature(meow).parameters.values()}
{'a': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'b': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'c': <_ParameterKind.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 1>, 
 'd': <_ParameterKind.KEYWORD_ONLY: 1>}
```

Aside from the PEPs, I also found this [quick summary](https://deepsource.io/blog/python-positional-only-arguments/) helpful to understanding the behavior.